# How to transform plain text to xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have tried diffrent way to process this information to xml, nothing is working.

Please help

I have a multiple line within one tag. I have to convert those to a proper xml document.

Here is the text/string

```
  <params>
         userdata_token=>'abd'
         userdata_time=>'12/09/2011'
         user_message_address_city=>'Manchester|Harrow|'
         user_message_address_postcode=>'M20 7LD||HA0 4BN'
         user_message_address_addressee=>'|Pete|'
  </params>
```

To xml format like

```
  <params>
    <userdata>
      <token>abd</temp>
      <time>12/09/2011</time>
    </userdata>
    <user>
      <message>
         <address>
           <city>Manchester</city>
           <postcode>M20 7LD</postcode>
           <addressee></addressee>
         </address>     
         <address>
           <city>Harrow</city>
           <postcode></postcode>
           <addressee>Pete</addressee>
         </address>  
         <address>
           <city></city>
           <postcode>HA0 4BN</postcode>
           <addressee></addressee>
         </address>  
       </message>
      <user>    
  </params>
```

Please could somebody help in spliting the string to hierarchical elements and corresponding value, I am looking to do this in XSL and Java, out put is well formed xml. I dont have the xsd for the out put, so I cant used binding schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is actually quite handy in XSLT 2.0**.

For the purpose of a quick demo (not fully finished and polished, but gives you an idea of this kind of processing with XSLT 2.0) I have come up with this just in a few minutes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:my="my:my">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vLines" select=
             "tokenize(string(/*), '\s*&#xA;\s*')[.]"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:sequence select="my:ProcessLines($vLines)"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:function name="my:ProcessLines" as="element()*">
      <xsl:param name="pLines" as="xs:string*"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="$pLines">
        <xsl:sequence select="my:ProcessLine(.)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:function>

     <xsl:function name="my:ProcessLine" as="element()*">
      <xsl:param name="pLine" as="xs:string*"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vSides" select="tokenize($pLine, '=>')"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vLHS" select="$vSides[1]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vRHS" select=
          "substring($vSides[2],2, string-length($vSides[2])-2)"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vGendElement" select=
           "my:MakeElement(tokenize($vLHS, '_'))"/>

      <xsl:sequence select="my:ImplantValues($vGendElement, $vRHS)"/>
     </xsl:function>

     <xsl:function name="my:MakeElement" >
      <xsl:param name="pElemNames" as="xs:string*"/>

       <xsl:if test="not(empty($pElemNames))">
         <xsl:element name="{$pElemNames[1]}">
           <xsl:sequence select=
            "my:MakeElement($pElemNames[position() > 1])"/>
         </xsl:element>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:function>

     <xsl:function name="my:ImplantValues" as="element()*">
       <xsl:param name="pTree" as="element()"/>
       <xsl:param name="pValues" as="xs:string"/>

       <xsl:variable name="vValues" select="tokenize($pValues, '\|')[.]"/>

       <xsl:for-each select="$vValues[string-length(normalize-space()) > 0]">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$pTree">
          <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="."/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:function>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:param name="pValue"/>
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
           <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="$pValue"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
       <xsl:param name="pValue"/>

       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$pValue"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (it could also simply read the input from a file using the `unparsed-text()` function):

```
<params>
  userdata_token=>'abd'
  userdata_time=>'12/09/2011'
  user_message_address_city=>'Manchester|Harrow|'
  user_message_address_postcode=>'M20 7LD||HA0 4BN'
  user_message_address_addressee=>'|Pete|'
</params>
```

**the result is**:

```
<userdata>
   <token>abd</token>
</userdata>
<userdata>
   <time>12/09/2011</time>
</userdata>
<user>
   <message>
      <address>
         <city>Manchester</city>
      </address>
   </message>
</user>
<user>
   <message>
      <address>
         <city>Harrow</city>
      </address>
   </message>
</user>
<user>
   <message>
      <address>
         <postcode>M20 7LD</postcode>
      </address>
   </message>
</user>
<user>
   <message>
      <address>
         <postcode>HA0 4BN</postcode>
      </address>
   </message>
</user>
<user>
   <message>
      <address>
         <addressee>Pete</addressee>
      </address>
   </message>
</user>
```

To finish this, one needs only to add some grouping -- I am preparing to go to work now, so this could be done later today. :)

Comment: +1 For a great answer. @Sujith - Here's a link to another Dimitre Novatchev answer that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233120/creating-new-elements-through-text-processing-in-xslt

Comment: Thanks Dimitre I will try to adapt this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible in XSLT 2. Take a look at the unparsed-text function, you can use that to read the contents of the file. You can call unparsed-text-available first to make sure the file is accessible, so the XSL transformation doesn't fail if it isn't.

The string can then be split into lines and name/value pairs. Look at the tokenize, string-before, and string-after functions for how to do this. Finally, create the output structure you want using <xsl:element>.

Answer (score 0):

XSL doesn't really care what your output is; the input has to be well-formed XML. In this case, your XML *is* well-formed, but the text node contains some formatted information that you need to make sense of. My advice is to not be too set on using XSL. A straight parse using regex or even StringTokenizer will extract your data. From there it's easy to write the result document.